# It's possible to modify the left menu bar from kibana and delete elements from it?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

Im trying to personalize kibana and I want to delete enterprise search from the options menu.
[image]

It's there anyway that I can do this?

Comment: what version are you on?

Comment: We can fork and do whatever we want. I don't think the Kibana UI based on users and roles feature is expected to come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using Default space of Kibana. you can create your custom space and add only the required functionality. Please check space [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.11/xpack-spaces.html).